# Remove the UIlabel text from table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

i Have a table view and use custom cells for this. now i have set a clear button in my Bar. now on click of that UIBarButton i want to clear all the text inside the text field in the cells. How can i do this..??

```
  var DataSource = [NewAssessmentModel]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.DataSource.count
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let model = self.DataSource[indexPath.row]


    switch(model.assessmentControlType)
    {
    case .text:
         let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionWithTextField", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? QuestionWithTextField)!
         cell.model = model
         cell.indexPath = indexPath
         cell.txtAnswer.delegate = self
         cell.lblQuestion.text = model.labelText
         cell.indexPath   = indexPath

        return cell
  }
  }
```

now cell contains a txtAnswer as a UITextField. How can i clear the text fields of txtAnswer.

for clearing the fields:

```
func clearView(sender:UIButton)
{
   print("Clear Button clicked")


}
```

Comment: After pressing the "clear" button, what do you want to happen with the data in `dataSource`? Do you want to keep the data and just clear labels?

Comment: clear the UIText Field

Comment: The question is asking `txtAnswer`, not `lblQuestion`. Why the answers below are referring to `lblQuestion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all visible cell of tableView.

```
@IBAction func deleteText(_ sender: Any) {
   for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
      if let questionCell = cell as? QuestionWithTextField {
         // Hide your label here.
         // questionCell.lblQuestion.hidden = true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: delete the txtAnswer  UITextField..??

Comment: if you wanna hide, just use hidden property `questionCell.lblQuestion.hidden = true`

Answer (score 2):

The above code applies only for the cells that are visible.The cell values won't be cleared if it is not visible in the phone.

For this you need to loop through every table view cells. I think this one is the one of the good option for you.

```
    func clearView(sender:UIButton)
    {
        print("Clear Button clicked")
        for view: UIView in tableView.subviews {
            for subview: Any in view.subviews {
                if (subview is UITableViewCell) {
                    let cell = subview as? UITableViewCell
                    // do something with your cell

                    if let questioncell = cell as? QuestionWithTextField
                    {
                        questioncell.txtField.text = ""
                    }

                    // you can access any cells

                }
            }
        }
    }
```